# Rally Lookback API: SSO Authentication Errors

Tags: api, rally, lookbackapi

Our organization uses single sign-on functionality to log into Rally automatically for each user. Wit custom apps I have created in the past which use the Web Services API, this doesn't appear to cause any troubles, however, when a user who has SSO enabled tries to run an app which uses the Lookback API, a login box appears (shown below). Neither the user's SSO credentials or their previous Rally login credentials seem to work in gaining them access to the API.

[image]

My assumption that it is SSO causing this problem is strictly based on the fact that the few of us with it disabled do not run into these problems, however those using SSO encounter it every time.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: Hi, I'm a developer at Rally.  Yesterday, we deployed a version that should solve the problem.  We are currently testing the fix, and will give you another update later this morning.  If you like, you can also try to log in with SSO and see if the problem went away.  Sorry for the inconvience, Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jake's team at Rally deployed an update that should have resolved this issue. Don't hesitate to post back if it's still occurring or if there's other concerns.

Comment: As of today, 3/27/2013, we are still experiencing this issue. It seemed to be fixed for a couple of weeks, but now we're hearing from many people that the issue is back again. Did something change?

Comment: Thanks for letting us know Conner, I'm checking in with Jake's team to investigate the issue.

Comment: Looks like the Rally authentication team has fixed the issue. Let us know if you still see any issues.